# PT Serif alternative with old-style figures and ligatures

Tags: fonts, typography, font-recommendation, serif

I am looking for a free alternative to [PT Serif](https://www.paratype.com/public/) that supports old style number figures, good kerning, and some optional ligatures. I intend to use for personal usage in an [academic blog](http://hugosereno.eu).

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with Merriweather. It's a serif Google font that has 8 weights and old style figures.

[image: Fonts Sample Merriweather]
[Download it here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Merriweather)

Answer (score 0):

Stix 2 Text is excellent. It has all the normal number styles as well as small caps and ligatures, and a very suitable build for onscreen display.